# after I did git rebase it should so only one commit

Tags: javascript, html, git, github, gitlab

- I followed the steps for git rebase... now when i do git status it shows.
- and then git log it shows two commits.
- after I did git rebase it should so only one commit right??
- if it should one commit I would have executed this comment **git push origin [swim-kick] -f **
- now how should I need to proceed??

```or-tag-here
git log --oneline --graph --decorate=short --all 

* aaaa (HEAD -> swim-kick, origin/swim-kick) swim: width issue
* bbbb swim: functionError issue
*   cccc Merge branch 'swim-kick' of gitlab.usaa.com:country into swim-kick
|\
| * dddd swim: border for close
* | eeee swim: border for close
|/
```

Comment: Please show you actual command sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you could show the commands that you executed.
The steps you would follow:

```
git rebase origin/master -i
```

pick the first commit, squash or fixup the the rest of the commits.

If you followed the above steps, the other possibility could be that you if you branched out of branch A and not master, it shows the commits of branch A as well